# Таблица рейтинга персонажа

Tags: c#, разработка-игр

Я разработал для своего проекта таблицу рейтинга. В которой есть вкладка "Рейтинг по уровню". И тут влез в серьезную стагнацию, задав себе вопрос: а как правильно реализовать ситуацию, когда несколько или более игроков одинакового уровня? Нужно же как-то понять, что один игрок дошел до уровня к примеру 20-ого первым, а другой так же до 20, но уже второй и т. д.

Я нашел вроде бы верное для себя решение, сохранять `int` поле в базу, которая определяет место в рейтинге игрока его же уровня.

Может у кого нибудь есть мысль лучше, поделитесь пожалуйста своими вариантами, спасибо!

Comment: Ну, банально хранить дату достижения уровня, например?

Comment: @andreymal тоже как вариант, спасибо

Comment: Если база реляционная, можно оставить первую таблицу для персонажей, а вторую обновлять по мере достижения, тогда во второй в этом порядке будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одинаковый рейтинг - это одинаковый рейтинг, а уж в каком порядке их перечислять - дело ВТОРОЕ. К варианту "кто первый достиг, тот наверху" хочу добавить вариант "кто последний достиг, тот наверху" (эта система используется чаще всего). Аргументировать можно тем, что более старые достижения становятся менее значимыми в силу того, что игрок может просто уже не играть, а те, кто играют в данный момент, будут болтаться внизу, а им (и всем остальным) нужно себя видеть. К тому же это будет стимулировать игроков продолжать игру, а не удовлетворяться своими достижениями. Можно ещё добавить небольшую деградацию рейтинга с течением времени. Отдельно сделать зал славы - там уже кто первый достиг, тот и победил.